# No resource identifier found for attribute 'ProgressIndeterminate in package 'cn.pedant.sweetalert'

Tags: android, eclipse, import, youtube

I just watched a youtube video of setting a Stylish alert dialog in the project but the guy in the video was using Android Studio as development platform and i use Eclipse. So i just went to the mentioned GitHub link and downloaded the project library. Now i have imported that project library in my Eclipse. But inside one xml there is an error shown :

```
<com.pnikosis.materialishprogress.ProgressWheel
        android:id="@+id/progressWheel"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        wheel:progressIndeterminate="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

> error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'ProgressIndeterminate in package 'cn.pedant.sweetalert'

error was in the first line of above code snippet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lol. That's funny how I accidentally got the solution for the above problem. I just needed to replace the

`wheel:progressIndeterminate = "true"`

to

```
wheel:matProg_progressIndeterminate = "true"
```

and it worked like a charm.

Comment: This issue, and also a solution how to fix it is mentioned there - https://github.com/pedant/sweet-alert-dialog/issues/91