# Binary XML file line #32: You must supply a layout_height attribute

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am having this xml problems. I have checked my codes and i am pretty sure that all layout-height are implemented.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:wheel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".activity.PostPreview">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_viewPhotoFull"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_back" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCaption"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/relativePostDetails"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/baloo_thambi"
        android:text="Sample photo label"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativePostDetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/relativeComment"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_likesCount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner1"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp">

            <com.androidapp.instasocial.ui.CompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/like_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/like_icon"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/feed_options_icon_size"
                android:visibility="visible"
                wheel:fontPath="@string/font_fontawesome" />

            <com.androidapp.instasocial.ui.CompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_likecount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/baloo_thambi"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="32"
                android:textColor="@color/txtColor"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_viewsCount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/linear_likesCount"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner1"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ic_Seen"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:tint="@color/txtColor"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_visibility_mt" />

            <com.androidapp.instasocial.ui.CompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_viewsCount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/baloo_thambi"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="32"
                android:textColor="@color/txtColor"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_commentsCount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/linear_viewsCount"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner1"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/pink_200"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ic_Comments"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="2dp"
                android:tint="@color/white"
                android:visibility="visible"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_comment_bubble" />

            <com.androidapp.instasocial.ui.CompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_commentsCount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/baloo_thambi"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="32"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearActions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_sendMessage"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:rotation="320"
                android:tint="@color/white"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_send_mt" />

            <com.androidapp.instasocial.ui.CompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/iv_like_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/unlike_icon"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="28sp"
                android:visibility="visible"
                wheel:fontPath="@string/font_fontawesome" />

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivClickReward"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ruon_new_app_icon"
                android:visibility="visible" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeComment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_comment"
            style="@style/Transparent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/rounded_black_outline"
            android:hint="@string/add_a_new_comment"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="24dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_sendComment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:rotation="320"
            android:tint="@color/txtColor"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_send_mt" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my logcat:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Binary XML file line #32: You must supply a layout_height attribute.
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Binary XML file line #32: You must supply a layout_height attribute.
```

Comment: Are you sure that this is the same file in which logcat indicates error?

Comment: Yes. it directs me straight to the activity where my layout is inflated. this is really weird.

Comment: Okay, do you have any other layout inflated in same activity i.e. For dialogs and fragments?

Comment: check for line no 32 as it indicates error in line 32

Comment: @Shivam I did. It reflect straight to the TextView tvCaption. Also as you can all layout height attribute are set.

Comment: try cleaning the project then and rebuilding it again..

Comment: Try giving the `textSize: 16dp` instead of `16sp`. Try it and let me know @NulfoGernaQuijoyJr.

Comment: Hi all, after triple checking my code I have fixed this issue as I was extending my activity with FragmentActivity which is supposed to be AppCompatActivity. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @NulfoGernaQuijoyJr. Then please answer your own question and accept that question or delete this question.

Answer (score 0):

> No resource identifier found for attribute 'ProgressIndeterminate in
>   package 'cn.pedant.sweetalert'

if above error then [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42814860/6611895)